# Python SQLite3 How to extract specific tables only

Tags: python, python-2.7, sqlite, export-to-csv

I have a sqlite database that I want to extract specific tables from.
The database has thousands of table names.
I'm interested only in tables that startwith "contact_"
However there are many that are contactOLD, contact#### you name it.

I then need to extract the row data from each "contact_########" table and create a CSV or spreadsheet type document.  In total there are 1600 or so with unique names.

I had initially thought I could do this with a sqlite query but could not.
I then tried to write a small script to do this but I could not figure out how to setup conditionals for the cursor.execute to only grab the data from the tables of interest to me.

Any ideas?

Update**

```
import sqlite3

fname = raw_input("Enter your filename: ")
con = sqlite3.connect(fname)
cursor = con.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table'")
mydata = cursor.fetchall()
for lines in mydata:
    print lines
```

I have been able to get the tables to list.  I still need to add a condition to my WHERE for "contact_"  When I add it, I get only [] on my print.  I think I'm messing something up here.

****Update 2***
Thanks to @Olver W. below who got me on the right track with this.

```
fname = raw_input("Enter your filename: ")
con = sqlite3.connect(fname)
cursor = con.cursor()
for tablename in cursor.execute("SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table';"):
    if tablename[0].startswith('Contacts_'):
        tablename = str(tablename[0])
        query = "Select * FROM " + tablename
        query = str(query)
        data = cursor.execute(query)
        for items in data:
            print items
```

I'm going to output this to a spreadsheet in some cases or another SQLite database but in my test database it is selecting the appropriate criteria and outputting the rows correctly.  I can and will condense it a bit to make it cleaner but it does the trick.  Thanks

Comment: You could first get the list of all the tables present in the database from which extract a list containing tables which start with `contact` and then construct individual queries by iterating over this list of tables name.

Comment: If I add the condition "contact" I get nothing.  I think I need to add a wildcard or something.  Added an update above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you could first query all the table names, then go through them and check if the name condition is fulfilled, which can be done in Python:

```
for tablename in cur.execute('SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type="table";'):
    if tablename[0].startswith('conn_'):
        execute_some_query_using_this_table()
```

Comment: Thanks, that is a much better.  But how do I refer to the table in each iteration  A standard Select * from iteration doesn't seem to work.  I tried using a data = cursor.fetchall() for rows in data: print data but it doesn't seem to print anything.  thanks

Comment: @BillSam, I don't understand. Have you tried replacing the `execute_some_query_using_this_table` by `cur.execute('SELECT * from ?', tablename[0])`?

Comment: I tried that first (I think) and got a syntax error for the SQL query.  I think it was because the iteration was a tuple.  So I ended up converting it to string in a new variable and then calling the variable as the cursor.execute.  I'm still figuring out this website so I'm not sure how to affix the code here so I'll edit the original and add what ended up working on my test database (which was substantially smaller)  thanks @Oliver